# local folder permissions vs chown -- security considerations

Tags: directory, permissions

I was trying to install a plugin, and I kept getting the following error:

> Unpacking the package…
>   Could not create directory.

I'm on Localhost on a XAMPP stack on Mac OS X Yosemite.

The way I solved this was by changing the `wp-content` folder's permissions in Finder, so that `everyone` could write to not only the folder but also to all enclosed items.

Per the image below, I right clicked on (1), then changed (2) to "Read & Write" and then chose "apply to enclosed items" in (3).

The proper way to solve this would have been to give the correct `user` write permission to the `wp-content` folder by using the `chown` command.

I didn't use the `chown` command because (1) I'm still learning how to use it, and (2) it's not clear to me which `user` is supposed to be given permission to... whether it's the `apache user` or the `ftp user` (I'll figure it out eventually).

My question is, if I were to migrate this wordpress site to an online domain based on an Ubuntu server, **what are the security implications of my having given `everyone` write access to this folder and how should I deal with them**?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Wp-content contains plugins and themes. So, if I can read and write into those files, I could add malicious code very easily. This malicious code can then do [interesting things](http://ottopress.com/2010/anatomy-of-a-theme-malware/). You are basically inviting a lot of trouble.

As for not understanding permissions:

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/04/unix-file-and-directory-permissions/

http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

Comment: Thanks. As I understand it, there's an apache user, and a Wordpress ftp user. Which user should get access to this folder? Also, what's the relationship with www-data? No need to explain it here, if you have a great article you can recommend, that'll be fine.

Comment: Both, in fact. _www-data_ is the user under which Apache runs. So, www-data (in a way =Apache) needs read, write and execute permissions to run all the code.

Usually this user will have ftp permissions (ftp user), as well to fetch plugins, themes or WordPress itself for installations and updates. That's that. Infact, all this isn't special about WordPress. These are general linux concepts:

http://serverfault.com/questions/357108/what-permissions-should-my-website-files-folders-have-on-a-linux-webserver

http://fideloper.com/user-group-permissions-chmod-apache

Answer (score 1):

I followed several links that suggested to:

1. Get ownership of wp-content folder: `sudo chown -R <usernam>  wp-content`
2. Set the correct uploads folder through the wp-content/option.php file: `sudo nano wp-admin/options.php`
3. Own the Plugins folder: `sudo chown www-data:www-data plugins -R`
4. Own the wp-content folder: `sudo chown www-data:www-data wp-content -R`
5. Change uploads folder permissions: `sudo chmod 755 -R uploads`
6. Change plugins folder permissions: `sudo chmod 755 -R plugins`

Even though all of them make sense, nothing worked. What worked for me was a much more simple solution.

```
sudo nautilus
```

and then i changed folder permissions thorough the GUI. 
[image]

It actually does exactly the same as above, but succeeds.